# For an integer $a$, prove $[a]_n$ is a subset of $[a]_m$ if only if $n$ divides $m$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Let $a$ be an integer, prove $[a]_n$ is a subset of $[a]_m$ if only if $n|m$.

I wanted to prove it by choosing an element $x$ and showing that if If $x≡ a \bmod m$ and $ x ≡ a \bmod n$, then $n$ divides $m$.

So for the forward step can I assume $x=a+mk$ and $x=an+nr$, $k,r$   integer? And want to show $n=mq$. From assumption, I got $mk=nr$. How do I show $n=mq$, for some integer $q$?

Comment: This is very badly written! Also it is false. $1 \equiv 1 \bmod n$ for any integer...are you really trying to claim that every integer divides every other integer?

Comment: Are you asking whether if $m$ divides $x-a$ and $n$ divides $x-a$ then $m$ divides $n$? If one puts it that way, the answer is "not necessarily."

Comment: Sorry for bad writing. To be honest, I don't get this problem at all. I have only one sentence given, 'let a an integer, prove [a]n is a subset of [a]m if only if n|m'

Answer (score 1):

As has been pointed out in comments, from $x\equiv a\pmod{m}$ and $x\equiv a \pmod{n}$ we cannot conclude that $n$ divides $m$.

It is not necessarily true that if $n$ divides $m$ then $[a]_n\subseteq [a]_m$. 
For example, let $n=2$, $m=4$, and $a=0$. Then $[a]_n$ consists of all multiples of $2$, and $[a]_m$ consists of all multiples of $4$. Certainly it is not the case 
that $[a]_n\subseteq [a]_m$. But it **is** true that $[a]_m\subseteq [a]_n$. When the proposed result is corrected, we can prove it using the intuition that you had.

Suppose first that $n$ divides $m$. Then if $x\equiv a\pmod{m}$, we can conclude that $x\equiv a \pmod{n}$. For if $m$ divides $x-a$ and $n$ divides $m$, then $n$ divides $x-a$. Thus $[a]_m\subseteq [a]_n$. (Note the direction of the containment.)

For the other direction, suppose that $[a]_m \subseteq [a]_n$. We show that $n$ divides $m$.

So we are told that for **every** $x$ such that $m$ divides $x-a$, we have that $n$ divides $x-a$. Let $x=a+m$. Then $m$ divides $x-a=m$. We conclude that $n$ divides $x-a$, meaning that $n$ divides $m$.

Comment: Thank you!That make sense.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what my solution says. You can skip the first two paragraphs, in a long-winded way they say the result as stated is wrong. Then (last three paragraphs) a proof of the correct result is given. The letters $a$ and $b$ should have been used! The letters $m$ and $n$ are too alike, it is easy to interchange them.

Comment: When you say x=a+m, shouldn't it be x=a+mk, for k integer?If it doesn't matter, why it doesn't matter?

Comment: I am trying to prove that from $[a]_m \subseteq [a]_n$ we can conclude $n$ divides $m$. If I used $mk$ instead of $m$, the conclusion would be that $n$ divides $mk$. If $k=1$, that gives me what I want to prove. If I choose  $k\gt 1$, it doesn't give me what I want.